# How to hide the class with values less than 1.6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which hides all rows with values 1.6.

```
$('.ind').filter(function() {
 return $(this).text().indexOf("1.6") !== -1;
}).parent().hide();
```

I am interested in a code which hides values less than 1.6.

Please see this  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sithelo/LWBYY/4/).

Comment: Please provide an example of the content of the elements. Looks like `return $(this).text() < 1.6;` should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the value to compare it as a number:

```
$('.ind').filter(function() {
  return parseFloat($(this).text()) < 1.6;
}).parent().hide();
```

The code in the question looks for the value 1.6 inside the string, which leads me to think that there may be other text than the number in the cell. If so, you would need to remove that before parsing:

```
$('.ind').filter(function() {
  return parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, '')) < 1.6;
}).parent().hide();
```

---

To check for a range, put the parsed value in a variable, then compare it to the lower and upper limit and return the result:

```
$('.ind').filter(function() {
  var value = parseFloat($(this).text());
  return value >= 1.6 && value < 1.7;
}).parent().hide();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. How do you filter a range. Say between 1.6 and 1.7?

Comment: @SitheloNgwenya: Then you compare the value to the lower and upper limit. I added an example above.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. You have been helpful. Check out this link http://jsfiddle.net/sithelo/LWBYY/4/ . Surprisingly its not hiding 1.5.

Comment: @SitheloNgwenya: You don't have any code that hides those rows. The code for the second and third radio button only shows the rows with the specified values, they don't hide the other rows. I suggest that you first show all rows and then hide the filtered rows (or vice versa).

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.ind').filter(function() {
var Value = parseFloat($(this).text()); 
return (value < 1.6);
}).parent().hide();
```

Comment: +1 for edit with base 10 even now seems like all modern browsers use base 10 by default

Comment: Parsing for example the string `1.7` as an integer give you the value `1`, which would cause it to be hidden although it's not less than 1.6.

Comment: @roasted: Parsing a string that starts with a zero causes `parseInt` to use base 8 instead.

Comment: Ya should be parseFloat() for sure

Comment: @Guff Updated, and I appreciate you letting me in on that ;) - I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ind').filter(function() {
    var floatValue = parseFloat($(this).text());
    return (floatValue < 1.6);
}).parent().hide();
```